# Bootstrap Modal backdrops

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have 2 different bootstrap modals on a single page I would like the 2 .modal-backdrop classes to behave differently. How do I achieve that?
Here is the sample code:

```
<!-- Cancel Modal --> 
<div class="modal fade" id="cancelModal"
   tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="cancelModal"
   aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="cancelModalLabel">Cancel Warning</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            Are you sure you want to cancel the form?
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
               dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
               (click)="cancel()">Yes</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- Submit Modal -->   
<div class="modal fade" id="submitModal" tabindex="-1"
   role="dialog" aria-labelledby="submitModal" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="submitModalLabel">Submit Warning</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            Are you sure you want to submit and close the form?
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/submission" 
               (click)="submitForm()">Yes</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Stavm I was not able to properly format the code. How did you do that?

Comment: what do you mean "behave differently" ? what is the expected behavior for each ?

Comment: I want to apply this code on one of them. I am not able to use the id to point to any of them.
.modal-backdrop {
  display: none !important;
}

Comment: can you do something like `.modal-backdrop:first-child { display: none !important; }`  ?

Comment: @Amir I don't think so since there is only one that is displayed at a time. It is not a list.

Comment: So you what is the question? you have only one backdrop, what do you want to do with that one backdrop?

Comment: I only want one of the 2 to be styled like the code in the comment above. How do I do that?

Comment: create a class with `display:none` as its rule, and toggle the adding of that class to the .backdrop element when required. if already, I highly suggest you use `ngx-bootstrap` they have a feature that does exactly that. https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-disable-backdrop

Comment: @Stavm, thank you for your suggestion. I thought about that but I do not have access to .backdrop class in the  code provided by the bootstrap team. Do you have any idea on how to access .backdrop?

Comment: sure you do. on your `styles.css` / `styles.scss` you can place whatever global-css rules you'd like.

Comment: Yes but my question is given the html code above where will I add the class before I style it?